# Hide/Show related elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So, I have this code with some buttons and contents. When a button is clicked, I want the div container to hide/show. Here is a part of the HTML code I use:

```
<li>
   <input type="button" id="hideshow" class="showhide1" value="hide/show">
   <div id="content" class="showhide1" style="display: none;">Hello World</div>
</li>
<li>
   <input type="button" id="hideshow" class="showhide2" value="hide/show">
   <div id="content" class="showhide2" style="display: none;">Hello World</div>
</li>
And it goes on like maybe a 100 times O.o...
```

And here is the jQuery I use:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
         jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {        
            jQuery('#content').toggle('hide');
         });
    });
</script>
```

This code kind of works but all the buttons hide/show's only the first content div. I think its because I have the same ID's in everything.

But I have different Classes, so I was wondering, if I can take the class of the clicked button and then show the content of the div with has the same class as pressed button. Can this be done or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/7xFtu/)

First you have to change the ID's into classes because in HTML ID's are meant to be unique.

```
<li>
    <input type="button" class="hideshow showhide1" value="hide/show" />
    <div class="content showhide1" style="display: none;">Hello World</div>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="button" class="hideshow showhide2" value="hide/show" />
    <div class="content showhide2" style="display: none;">Hello World</div>
</li>
```

Then you can select the content div which is a sibling.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.hideshow').on('click', function(event) {        
        jQuery(this).siblings(".content").toggle('hide');
    });
});
```

- P.S - Notice the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function is deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and was removed in jQuery 1.9. I'm using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: OMG I am so noob on this. This solution works. Thanks alot people. You guys are awesome. :)

Comment: Okai, I will do that. :)

Comment: my answer is also working fine... actually it will work better than this

Comment: @Patel Not that I care, but how exactly is it better?

Answer (score 1):

first of all.. as always **ID should always be unique**... use class instead.. and `live()` is deprecated use `on`

without changing most of your code.

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('ul').on('click','.showhide1,.showhide2', function(event) {        
     jQuery(this).next().toggle('hide'); //<--using next()
});
});
```

you can also use siblings or closest instead of next...

```
jQuery(this).siblings('.content').toggle('hide'); //<--using siblings()
jQuery(this).closest('.content').toggle('hide'); //<--using closest()
```

however you can add same class to all the elements and use class selector

```
  jQuery('ul').on('click','.elementsClass', function(event) {        
     jQuery(this).next().toggle('hide');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>
<input type="button" id="hideshow" class="showhide" value="hide/show">
<div id="content" style="display: none;">Hello World</div>
</li>
<li>
<input type="button" id="hideshow" class="showhide" value="hide/show">
<div id="content" style="display: none;">Hello World</div>
</li>
```

And here is the jQuery you should use:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.showhide').on('click', function(event) {        
         $(this).next().toggle();
    });
    });
</script>
```